# C++ printf only appear in the end

Tags: c++, c

This is the program that I was trying to make to learn

the program works but the message "type the rectangle height" and "type the rectangle width" only appear when the program is over

```
#include < stdio.h >

using namespace std;

float calculateArea(float a, float b)
{
    return a * b;
}

float calculatePerimeter(float a, float b)
{
    return 2*a + 2*b;
}

void showMessage(char *msg, float vlr)
{
    printf("%s %5.2f", msg, vlr);
}

int main()
{
    float height, width, area, perimeter;

    printf("type the rectangle height");

    scanf("%f%*c", &height);

    printf("type the rectangle width");

    scanf("%f%*c", &width);

    area = calculateArea(height, width);

    perimeter = calculatePerimeter(height, width);

    showMessage("The area value is =", area);

    showMessage("The perimeter value is =", perimeter);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's because printf is not putting chars onto the screen instantly. It first copy it to buffer memory. To actually show something on screen application need to synchronize buffer with screen. You can do that with `fflush(stdout)` but you can also add end of line char ("\n") inside your string. It's because standard output buffer is often automatically synchronize when it find '\n'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can print a newline:

```
printf("\n");
```

or using C++ iostreams

```
cout << endl;
```

If you wish, you can force the program to flush its output stream:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

or using C++ iostreams

```
cout << flush;
```

This saves you from having to type a newline if you don't wish to do so.

Comment: To be more specific printf and fflush are correct functions also in c++ not only in C.

Comment: If this helped you out, could you please accept this answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print a newline:

```
void showMessage(char *msg, float vlr)
{
    printf("%s %5.2f\n", msg, vlr);
    //          ----^
}
```

The reason is because, by default, `stdout` is *line-buffered* - that means the content you write to the stream is buffered until a newline character is written. At that point, the buffer will be flushed and actually written to the console.

Comment: But the error is in "type the rectangle height" and "type the rectangle width"
can I do the same thing?